# Firefox mangles theme after update

Tags: firefox, updates, themes, default-settings, dark-mode

Whenever Firefox restarts, it ends up looking like this:
[image: after update]
I then go to the theme settings and <kbd>Disable</kbd> the *Dark* theme:
[image: settings]
This gives me the look I want:
[image: good]
Strangely, after this, I can <kbd>Enable</kbd> and <kbd>Disable</kbd> that same theme, with no visual effect other than *Dark* and *System theme* switching place and status.

**Is there a way to keep this look when updating?**